# Object-capability security in Racket?

Tags: security, racket

Racket's sandbox seems great for running code I don't trust, but I would like to prevent modules that call one another in the sandbox from being able to see or modify one another's internal state, code, or behavior. Right now the best way I can think of to do that is with separate sandboxes and a modified "require" that wraps all exported functions in contracts that create proxies. Is there a better way?

Comment: What code have you tried?

Answer (score -1):

Could you provide a concrete example?

If module A requires module B, then module A can't see inside B. 
Module A can use the functions that module B explicitly provided.
Some of these might change internal state in module B.

Comment: So far the main problem I have found is with introspection and reflection and dynamic evaluation: module B can use namespace-set-variable-value! and friends to modify top-level bindings. Stuff in A that doesn't use eval is probably safe, but that means I should probably remove eval and/or the introspection functions.

Comment: @SeanLynch I recommend re-asking this question on the Racket mailing list. I think your question could lead to a nice discussion.

Comment: Thanks! I have a couple more things to try and then I'll try posting something more concrete and detailed to the list.

Comment: No response after a couple of days on the list, not even a "huh

Comment: Whoops, turns out someone had responded, just to me directly and not the list, so I didn't see it under the list tag. Shows you how well I keep up on my personal email. They suggested developing a #lang and pointed me at shill-lang.org and their paper about it. I will look into that.